# Star Trek episode where Tuvok is confused with time

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

What episode does Tuvok ask "what about the delta flyer?" And someone says "the what?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Voyager: Fury](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/620.htm)

> **TUVOK:** *The Delta Flyer. Its sensors are more advanced.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *The Delta what?*

---

Tuvok is indeed having trouble with time-flashes

> Tuvok has more intense hallucinations and collapses. At the same moment the Doctor and Janeway detect a burst of tachyon particles in Tuvok's vicinity, indicating temporal disturbances. His visions may actually be glimpses of the future.
>
> <sub><sup>[Fury (Star Trek: Voyager) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fury_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. It's hard for me to retain certain info.

Comment: @JeffLMaxwell - [No worries. Enjoy the episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ). Oh, and don't forget to upvote the answer :-)

Comment: I did, but with no rep, it won't affect the community standing. 1 more thing, is that buffy as your pro pic?

Comment: @JeffLMaxwell - Yeah, my avatar picture is always Buffy, but I try to rotate it every few weeks depending on my mood.

Comment: Cool beans. I'll probably see it change eventually. I'm thinking I'm gonna be on here a lot more.

Comment: @JeffLMaxwell, sure thing! Valorum has been here long before any of us, and will still be here when we all are gone.